# Reference for dual gauge field and magnetic field being canonically conjugate

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, yang-mills, duality

The gauge field operator in quantum Yang-Mills is canonically conjugate to the electric field.

I know that the *dual gauge field* is canonically conjugate to the magnetic field, but I can't seem to dig up a reference supporting this. Can someone provide a reference for this please?

Comment: I found eq. (6.28) in https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.01817